# Pandas multiindex Ranking and Sorting

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a sorting problem.

| TOT_ENERGY_CONSUMPTION | REGION_CODE | INDUSTRY_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11289.15 | 110101 | I65 |
| 11407.056 | 110101 | M73 |
| 14898.249 | 110101 | I63 |
| 9718.287 | 110102 | M7d |
| 9957.729923 | 110102 | I6s |
| 10653.603 | 110103 | M7s |
| 12673.787 | 110103 | I6c |
| 13101.499 | 110103 | M7w |

I would like my final output table be sorted to the following:

| TOT_ENERGY_CONSUMPTION | REGION_CODE | INDUSTRY_CODE | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14898.249 | 110101 | I65 | 1 |
| 11407.056 | 110101 | M73 | 2 |
| 11289.15 | 110101 | I63 | 3 |
| 9957.729923 | 110102 | M7d | 1 |
| 9718.287 | 110102 | I6s | 2 |
| 13101.499 | 110103 | M7s | 1 |
| 12673.787 | 110103 | I6c | 2 |
| 10653.603 | 110103 | M7w | 3 |

Sorting by fixing REGION_CODE and sort TOT_ENERGY_CONSUMPTION. Then add ranking to region_code

I tried several times and no fruit.

Comment: Please ignore INDUSTRY_CODE. INDUSTRY_CODE should be match whatever the row changes are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['REGION_CODE', 'TOT_ENERGY_CONSUMPTION'], 
                    ascending=[True, False],
                    ignore_index=True
                    )
df["rank"] = df.groupby(['REGION_CODE']).cumcount().add(1)
print (df)
   TOT_ENERGY_CONSUMPTION  REGION_CODE INDUSTRY_CODE  rank
0            14898.249000       110101           I63     1
1            11407.056000       110101           M73     2
2            11289.150000       110101           I65     3
3             9957.729923       110102           I6s     1
4             9718.287000       110102           M7d     2
5            13101.499000       110103           M7w     1
6            12673.787000       110103           I6c     2
7            10653.603000       110103           M7s     3
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want:

```
df["rank"] = df.groupby(['REGION_CODE'])["TOT_ENERGY_CONSUMPTION"].rank("dense", ascending=False)
df = df.sort_values(['REGION_CODE','rank'])
```

which gives

```
TOT_ENERGY_CONSUMPTION  REGION_CODE INDUSTRY_CODE  rank
2            14898.249000       110101           I63   1.0
1            11407.056000       110101           M73   2.0
0            11289.150000       110101           I65   3.0
4             9957.729923       110102           I6s   1.0
3             9718.287000       110102           M7d   2.0
7            13101.499000       110103           M7w   1.0
6            12673.787000       110103           I6c   2.0
5            10653.603000       110103           M7s   3.0
```

Comment: Your first solution is the right but you have to sort by region and rank now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `groupby_rank` then `sort_values`:

```
out = df.assign(RANK=df.groupby('REGION_CODE', sort=False)['TOT_ENERGY_CONSUMPTION']
                       .rank('dense', ascending=False).astype(int)) \
        .sort_values(['REGION_CODE', 'RANK'])
print(out)

# Output
   TOT_ENERGY_CONSUMPTION  REGION_CODE INDUSTRY_CODE  RANK
2            14898.249000       110101           I63     1
1            11407.056000       110101           M73     2
0            11289.150000       110101           I65     3
4             9957.729923       110102           I6s     1
3             9718.287000       110102           M7d     2
7            13101.499000       110103           M7w     1
6            12673.787000       110103           I6c     2
5            10653.603000       110103           M7s     3
```